# asp.net placeholders side by side

Tags: asp.net

I have a webpage in asp.net that I am trying to lay out and I have a couple of placeholders that get filled with datagridviews full of information from a database.

This is simple enough to do with 2 placeholders and then then tables appear one above the other.  What I would like to do is figure out how to do this so that the tables will end up appearing side by side.

I would prefer to keep the placeholder based design of the page so that if the tables from the database end up being different sizes, this doesn't break anything on the webpage.

Thanks for any help that you can provide.

Comment: Why use placeholders instead of just putting gridviews directly on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see why you wouldn't just use a 2-column CSS layout, and put one placeholder in the left column, and the other in the right column.

If you're not familiar with CSS, search for [2 column CSS layout](http://www.google.com/search?q=2+column+css+layout) in Google.